# final variable initialization in derived class

Tags: java, final

I am confused if we can initialize the final variable of the base class in its derived class.
My base class is

```
    abstract class MyClass1 {
        //Compiler Error:Variable is not initialized in the default constructor.

        public final int finalVar;
    }
    //And my derived class with variable initialization.

    class DerivedClass extends MyClass1 {
        DerivedClass()
        {
            super();
            //Cannot asssign a value to finalVar.
            finalVar = 1000;
        }
   }
```

Please tell me if it is possible to initialize the final variable in the derived class. Will it just give a compile time error or also will a runtime error?

Comment: `Is it just give the compile time error or also will give the runtime error.` - if your code doesn't pass compilation, you can't run it, so there will be no runtime for this code.

Comment: You should refer to the final variable declaration documentation!

Comment: Doesn't the compilation error make it clear that the final field must be initialized by the base class constructor(s)?

Comment: Why have you not run this and found the answer for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

A final variable needs to be initialized in the constructor, which your abstract class lacks. Adding that constructor then allows you to call it via super(). Consider the following example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        baseClass instance = new derivedClass(1);
    }
}

abstract class baseClass {
    protected final int finalVar;
    baseClass(int finalVar){
        this.finalVar = finalVar;
    }
}

class derivedClass extends baseClass {
    derivedClass(int finalVar){
        super(finalVar);
        System.out.println(this.finalVar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assign a value to your variable in the parent class.

```
// Declaring Parent class
class Parent {
    /* Creation of final variable pa of string type i.e 
    the value of this variable is fixed throughout all 
    the derived classes or not overidden*/
    final String pa = "Hello , We are in parent class variable";
}
// Declaring Child class by extending Parent class
class Child extends Parent {
    /* Creation of variable ch of string type i.e 
    the value of this variable is not fixed throughout all 
    the derived classes or overidden*/
    String ch = "Hello , We are in child class variable";
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creation of Parent class object
        Parent p = new Parent();
        // Calling a variable pa by parent object 
        System.out.println(p.pa);
        // Creation of Child class object
        Child c = new Child();

        // Calling a variable ch by Child object 
        System.out.println(c.ch);
        // Calling a variable pa by Child object 
        System.out.println(c.pa);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Final members need to be initialized in the constructor of the class.  You can modify your code to have the subclass pass the value via the constructor:

```
abstract class MyClass1 {

    public final int finalVar;

    protected MyClass1(int var) {
         finalVar = var;
    }

} 

class DerivedClass extends MyClass1 {
    DerivedClass() {
        super(1000);
    }
}
```